# Proof of $\Pr(A\mid B)\ge (a+b-1)/b$

Tags: probability

> Prove that if $\Pr(A) = a$ and $\Pr(B) = b>0$, then
>   $$\Pr(A\mid B) \ge \frac{a+b-1}{b}.$$

So far I have gotten
P(A∣B)=P(A∩B)/P(B)=P(A∩B)/b,
so p(AnB)> or equal to 1,
pr(a)+pr(b)-p(AUB)> a+b-1,
canceling the a+b,
I have Aub> or equal to 1

....but that can't be right?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Also, cancelling the quantity $a+b$ from both sides, yields $-p(A\cup B) \ge -1$.

Comment: Yes. this is the problem I wanted to prove. I can't believe I made such a careless error. So because (AnB) being less than or equal to 1 is a given does this mean the proof is done? Forgive me for the obvious questions, it's been a very long time since I have last done a proof.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to start in a very good way.

Also, $$\Pr(A\cup B) \le 1\implies -\Pr(A\cup B) \ge -1.$$  Adding to both sides the quantity $\Pr(A) + \Pr(B)$ gives:
$$\Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A\cup B) \ge \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) -1.$$ Just notice what the LHS is (and what you want to prove) and the proof is almost done.

Comment: Negation of less than or equal to should be only greater than?

Comment: @AmadeusBachmann Yes, that's true.

Comment: Why would I remove the a+b portion and then bring it back? What is LHS? And thank you so much again for looking at this.